# How to make a deep nested part of code be toggled without making 2 versions of it

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested-loops

I have the following structure of code:

```
for
 for
  for
   for
    {
    things
    if(condition1||condition2)
    }
```

And basically that "if" checks 2 variables that depends of every loop before it, but only have to be checked if the user said so at the beginning of the program, otherwise that "if" is pointless.

I could use `if(boolean&&(condition1||condition2))` which would work great except for the fact that it would be checked for every single iteration of all the loops.

So my question is: Is there a way to get C++ to disable that "if" completely (without checking a condition every loop) if the user said so, without repeating itself with and without the if??? Like, for example:

```
if(boolean)
 {
  all the fors
    things
    if(conditio1||condition2)
 }
else
 {
  all the fors
    things
 }
```

This works fine but if I have to make any change in the future, I would have to write it 2 times with the possibility of forgetting about the second time or making mistakes. And I also have other 3 parts of code with the same issue, so the code would get really long.

Edit: Some of you think we are talking of insignificant numbers of iterations, but that "if" would have to be checked at least 10.8 millions times by the end of each complete program. And as I said, I have (now 2) more parts of code with the same issue, so quite some time could have been saved.
Too bad the solution of `if constexpr` used C++17

Comment: There are ways, yes, but first, did you verify that the check is not optimized away when you enable optimizations?

Comment: Do what you said, `if(boolean&&(condition1||condition2))`. Avoid trying to optimize it until and unless there's a noticeable performance degradation--I'd be shocked if there were one.

Comment: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We *should* forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil." —Donald Knuth

Comment: Most likely you will  obscure your  program, making it  harder to maintain, and you'll gain for this a few microseconds of its execution time. So - do experiment, and chose wisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your code in a function like this

```
template<bool Boolean>
void code(/* parameters */)
{
  for // ...
    for // ...
      // all the fors ...
      {
         // things 
         if constexpr (Boolean)  // compile time branch
         {
            if(condition1 || condition2)
               // ...
         }
      }
}
```

The `if constexpr` will only be compiled when the `Boolean` is true. So at the call site you can do

```
bool boolean = /* some run-time initialization */
if (boolean)
  code<true>(/* arguments */);
else 
  code<false>(/* arguments */);
```

Note that this is not something you should do for the sake of performance, unless you've measured and profiled the code to see if it's a bottleneck. Once you've done that, you can use the above technique.

---

If you're not yet using C++17, the entire `if constexpr` block can be replaced by

```
work<Boolean>(/* arguments */);
```

where `work` is a function template that's specialized to only do work in the `true` case:

```
template<bool>
void work(/* parameters */) {}  

template<>
void work<true>(/* parameters */) 
{
  if(condition1 || condition2)
     // ...
}
```

Comment: from what the OP described this won't be possible because the the condition is known at runtime (start of the program as per OP description).

Comment: @bolov That's perfectly fine. Depending on the runtime value of `boolean`, either `code<true>` or `code<false>` is executed. I'll edit the identifier names to make it clear what's going on.

Comment: This looks like it, but it is for C++17 and we are using C++11 at best. Well I'll do what other suggests and try to keep it simple with the original idea, what a pity, it would have been so much nicer that way

Comment: @byrey3 The `if constexpr` is not necessary for this technique, it's just convenient that way. I've added an alternative that works pre-C++17 as well. By the way, in the future, make sure to add the relevant revision tag, such as [tag:c++11] to make it clear which revision you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Move your for-loops into a function and use a callback as an function argument.

```
#include <iostream>

void func(void (*callback)(int i, int j)) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      std::cout << "i = " << i << ", j = " << j << ", (i + j) % 3 == " << (i + j) % 3 << "\n";
      callback(i, j);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  bool verbose = false;
  std::cin >> verbose;
  if (verbose) {
    func([](int i, int j){ if((i + j) % 3 == 0) std::cout << "Their sum is divided by three.\n" ; });
  }
  else {
    func([](int i, int j){});
  }
}
```